# Raspberry Pi 3B+ freezes on cron reboot

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os, cron, crash, reboot

I set up a cronjob on my Raspberry Pi 3B+ (1GB RAM) to reboot every morning, which worked fine for over a year. For three days, however, the RPi has been crashing immediately after reboot.

By “crashing” I mean “freezing” or “becoming unresponsive” – I don't know whether it still runs at all, since it won't react to anything I do (no SSH, all services down etc.). My work-around is to plug out the power cord and plug it in again. After that, the RPi boots (seemingly) fine, at least all services work again and I can log in via SSH.

What might cause this issue and how could I possibly fix it? Thank you!

## Debug info

```
pi@raspberrypi: ~$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux

pi@raspberrypi: ~$ df -h
Dateisystem    Größe Benutzt Verf. Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/root        29G     13G   16G   46% /
devtmpfs        325M       0  325M    0% /dev
tmpfs           455M       0  455M    0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           182M    3,4M  179M    2% /run
tmpfs           5,0M    4,0K  5,0M    1% /run/lock
/dev/mmcblk0p1  255M     31M  225M   13% /boot
tmpfs            91M     20K   91M    1% /run/user/1000

pi@raspberrypi: ~$ crontab -e
@reboot nohup /home/pi/snowflake/proxy/proxy > /home/pi/snowflake/proxy/snowflake.log 2>&1 &
@reboot telegraf --config /etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf

pi@raspberrypi: ~$ sudo crontab -e
40 4 * * * sudo reboot
```

When setting up my RPi, I had enabled unattended upgrades like this:

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow unattended-upgrades
sudo systemctl status unattended-upgrades.service
```

I had also configured the RPi in headless mode:

[image]

Here's a list of services that I run on my RPi (including since when I've been hosting them):

- AdGuard Home (for over a year)
- [Snowflake](https://snowflake.torproject.org) (for a year)
- InfluxDB (for a couple of weeks)
- Grafana (since few days after installing InfluxDB)

After setting up InfluxDB, I configured a USB stick as the swap memory:

```
pi@raspberrypi: ~$ sudo nano /etc/fstab
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=0f70ec87-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=0f70ec87-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=3cfb8767-d24c-48bd-86ad-8942793b5115 none swap sw 0 0
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

## Grafana charts

You can clearly see periods when no temperature stats were collected (InfluxDB was down due to the crash, just like the entire system):

[image]

The same for the CPU usage chart:

[image]

## `/var/log` files

I couldn't paste all of the log files here because they would've exceeded the maximum character count of 30,000 chars, so I uploaded

- `/var/log/syslog`
- `/var/log/daemon.log`
- `/var/log/kern.log`
- `/var/log/messages`

to my Nextcloud (no expiration date set): https://murena.io/s/3DAKSyRqiLgADD8

Sorry for the inconvenience.

### `/var/log/AdGuardHome.err`

Here's an excerpt from the AdGuard Home log file from around the time when the RPi crashed. As you can see, there is nothing noteworthy, just an interruption that lasted until I manually rebooted the system:

```
2023/08/14 00:10:52.307917 [error] dnsproxy: unpacking udp packet: dns: buffer size too small
2023/08/14 00:10:55.335954 [error] dnsproxy: unpacking udp packet: dns: buffer size too small
2023/08/14 00:16:27.504667 [error] dnsproxy: unpacking udp packet: dns: buffer size too small
2023/08/14 00:16:30.503943 [error] dnsproxy: unpacking udp packet: dns: buffer size too small
2023/08/14 04:40:01.707986 [info] service: action run has been done successfully on linux-systemd
2023/08/14 04:40:01.709148 [info] Received signal "terminated"
2023/08/14 04:40:01.709519 [info] stopping AdGuard Home
2023/08/14 11:21:23 [info] AdGuard Home, version v0.108.0-b.43
2023/08/14 11:21:23 [info] service: control action: run
2023/08/14 11:21:23.477455 [info] AdGuard Home, version v0.108.0-b.43
2023/08/14 11:21:23.477565 [info] AdGuard Home is running as a service
2023/08/14 11:21:23.492046 [info] tls: using default ciphers
2023/08/14 11:21:23.502639 [info] safesearch default: disabled
2023/08/14 11:21:23.638269 [info] Initializing auth module: /opt/AdGuardHome/data/sessions.db
2023/08/14 11:21:23.699760 [info] auth: initialized.  users:1  sessions:13
2023/08/14 11:21:23.749410 [info] tls: number of certs: 1
2023/08/14 11:21:29.471087 [info] web: initializing
2023/08/14 11:21:30.293886 [info] dnsproxy: cache: enabled, size 4096 b
2023/08/14 11:21:30.294035 [info] dnsproxy: max goroutines is set to 300
2023/08/14 11:21:30.297410 [info] clients: processing addresses
2023/08/14 11:21:30.302670 [info] AdGuard Home is available at the following addresses:
2023/08/14 11:21:30.303138 [info] go to https://raspberry.pi:8088
2023/08/14 11:21:30.304660 [info] go to http://127.0.0.1:8087
2023/08/14 11:21:30.304812 [info] go to http://[::1]:8087
```

### `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log`

```
logger=plugins.update.checker t=2023-08-14T04:33:30.697979208+02:00 level=info msg="Update check succeeded" duration=136.504001ms
logger=server t=2023-08-14T04:40:01.883841513+02:00 level=info msg="Shutdown started" reason="System signal: terminated"
logger=tracing t=2023-08-14T04:40:01.890031171+02:00 level=info msg="Closing tracing"
logger=ticker t=2023-08-14T04:40:02.285024744+02:00 level=info msg=stopped last_tick=2023-08-14T04:40:00+02:00
logger=settings t=2023-08-14T11:21:09.963289565+02:00 level=info msg="Starting Grafana" version=10.0.3 commit=eb8dd72637 branch=HEAD compiled=2023-07-25T19:55:59+02:00
```

### `/var/log/debug`

```
Aug 13 21:34:40 raspberrypi php7.4-mbstring: php_invoke mbstring: already enabled for PHP 7.4 cli sapi
Aug 13 21:34:41 raspberrypi php7.4-mbstring: php_invoke mbstring: already enabled for PHP 7.4 apache2 sapi
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s78504 r8192 d32088 u118784 alloc=29*4096
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.096640] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124313] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124332] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124348] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124377] Module dwc_common_port init
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.438860]   with arguments:
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.438876]     /sbin/init
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.438892]   with environment:
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.438906]     HOME=/
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.438921]     TERM=linux
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    5.484127] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.822844] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi thd[398]: Found socket passed from systemd
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Successfully called chroot.
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Successfully limited resources.
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Running.
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Watchdog thread running.
Aug 14 04:40:25 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Canary thread running.
Aug 14 04:40:26 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:26 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:26 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:26 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:26 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[848]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s78504 r8192 d32088 u118784 alloc=29*4096
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.096779] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124486] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124507] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124523] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.124553] Module dwc_common_port init
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.777384]   with arguments:
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.777400]     /sbin/init
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.777416]   with environment:
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.777430]     HOME=/
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    3.777445]     TERM=linux
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [    5.484224] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.998883] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi thd[393]: Found socket passed from systemd
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Successfully called chroot.
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Successfully dropped privileges.
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Successfully limited resources.
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Running.
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Watchdog thread running.
Aug 14 04:41:11 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Canary thread running.
Aug 14 04:41:12 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:12 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:12 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:12 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 2 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:12 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 3 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi rtkit-daemon[875]: Supervising 6 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s78504 r8192 d32088 u118784 alloc=29*4096
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi thd[396]: Found socket passed from systemd
...
```

### `/var/log/user.log`

```
Aug 14 04:40:01 raspberrypi grafana[1677]: logger=server t=2023-08-14T04:40:01.883841513+02:00 level=info msg="Shutdown started" reason="System signal: terminated"
Aug 14 04:40:01 raspberrypi grafana[1677]: logger=tracing t=2023-08-14T04:40:01.890031171+02:00 level=info msg="Closing tracing"
Aug 14 04:40:02 raspberrypi grafana[1677]: logger=ticker t=2023-08-14T04:40:02.285024744+02:00 level=info msg=stopped last_tick=2023-08-14T04:40:00+02:00
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3"
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.1"
Aug 14 04:40:13 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 04:40:19 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[585,root]: ServerManager: Server started
Aug 14 04:40:20 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[585,root]: ConsoleDisplay: Cannot find a running X server on vt1
Aug 14 04:40:27 raspberrypi pipewire[840]: Failed to receive portal pid: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop': no such name
Aug 14 04:40:30 raspberrypi pulseaudio[841]: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 14 04:40:30 raspberrypi pulseaudio[841]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="platform-3f902000.hdmi" card_name="alsa_card.platform-3f902000.hdmi" namereg_fail=false tsched=no fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.1"
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3"
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 04:40:59 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 04:41:05 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[578,root]: ServerManager: Server started
Aug 14 04:41:06 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[578,root]: ConsoleDisplay: Cannot find a running X server on vt1
Aug 14 04:41:13 raspberrypi pipewire[867]: Failed to receive portal pid: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get PID of name 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop': no such name
Aug 14 04:41:16 raspberrypi pulseaudio[868]: Failed to find a working profile.
Aug 14 04:41:16 raspberrypi pulseaudio[868]: Failed to load module "module-alsa-card" (argument: "device_id="1" name="platform-3f902000.hdmi" card_name="alsa_card.platform-3f902000.hdmi" namereg_fail=false tsched=no fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1""): initialization failed.
Aug 14 04:41:17 raspberrypi pulseaudio[868]: Found duplicated D-Bus path for adapter /org/bluez/hci0
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.3"
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 5: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1.1"
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Aug 14 11:21:15 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 5 was not an MTP device
...
```

### `/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-shutdown.log`

```
2023-08-01 04:40:03,477 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-02 04:40:02,370 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-02 21:23:12,174 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-02 21:35:45,862 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-03 00:46:23,362 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-03 04:40:03,563 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-04 04:40:02,322 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-05 04:40:02,769 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-06 04:40:04,135 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-07 04:40:02,830 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-08 04:40:02,940 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-09 04:40:04,721 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-10 04:40:03,076 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-11 04:40:02,682 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-12 04:40:02,736 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-13 04:40:03,958 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-13 12:51:16,042 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
2023-08-14 04:40:03,959 WARNING - SIGTERM or SIGHUP received, stopping unattended-upgrades only if it is running
```